# Diferença de Escrita de arquivos Java

Tags: java, arquivo

Gostaria de saber a diferença nesses dois métodos de Escrever em arquivos.

```
Path path = Paths.get("E:/documentos/texte.txt");

Charset utf8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

try(BufferedWriter escrever = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, utf8)) {
    escrever.write(" ");
}
```

Para  este:

```
File arq = new File("E:/documentos.texte.txt");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(arq);

try(BufferedWriter escrever = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {         
    escrever.write(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

De um modo direto, Path é mais moderno e faz tudo o que o File faz de uma maneira melhor.
Em novos projetos é recomendado usar Path.

Para mais informações [nesse link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903335/java-7-path-vs-file).

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro usar a primeira solução, ela usa a API de arquivos mais nova, que tem suas vantagens. Por exemplo é mais prático trabalhar com `Path` do que `String` para caminhos de arquivo.

Com relação ao resultado final (o arquivo gerado) existe uma diferença entre as duas soluções: na primeira solução usa-se UTF-8, já na segunda o contrutor do `FileWriter` usa o *encoding* 'padrão' do sistema operacional (SO), que varia de SO para SO.